# Bash How to delete record from destination file which matches with source up to 17th pipe

Tags: bash

My source file is a pipe delimited one

```
QWER|RTYUI||12345678|09/07/1994|DFGHJK||PHOENIX|AZ||85044|123456|QQ|4567890|10/06/2017|12/31/9999|N||1|1234567|QQ|4567890876
```

and so is my destination file (destination files will be in date partitioned folders)

```
QWER|RTYUI||12345678|09/07/1994|DFGHJK||PHOENIX|AZ||85044|123456|QQ|4567890|10/06/2017|12/31/9999|N|QQQ|NOMATCH
```

I should be able to pick a record from source file and loop through all of files in destination folders and remove the record from destination file, point to be noted is I only need to match data up to 17th pipe in both of the files because after that data mismatches.

Example

BEFORE:

Source file

```
QWER|RTYUI||12345678|09/07/1994|DFGHJK||PHOENIX|AZ||85044|123456|QQ|4567890|10/06/2017|12/31/9999|N||1|1234567|QQ|4567890876
```

Destination file

```
QWER|RTYUI||12345678|09/07/1994|DFGHJK||PHOENIX|AZ||85044|123456|QQ|4567890|10/06/2017|12/31/9999|N|QQQ|NOMATCH
QWER|RTYUI||98765432|09/07/1921|FGHJKJK||VBNM|AZ||85044|123456|QQ|4567890|10/06/2017|12/31/9999|N|QQQ|NOMATCH
```

AFTER:

Destination file

```
QWER|RTYUI||98765432|09/07/1921|FGHJKJK||VBNM|AZ||85044|123456|QQ|4567890|10/06/2017|12/31/9999|N|QQQ|NOMATCH
```

The first record should be deleted from destination file because it is matching the data with source file up to 17th pipe.

Comment: Could you please let us know if your files have any specific format? By seeing your output I could see 17th column you don't want, rather than removing all the fields from 17th field? Could you please do let us know on same.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, Updated my question, please let me know if that helps.

Comment: A belated welcome to the site!  Check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more about asking questions that will attract quality answers.  You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46667203/edit) to include more information.  What have you tried so far?  In general, I would use `awk` for this sort of task.

Comment: @KiranKumar, please use code tags for your sample inputs/codes in your post. Check my answer and let me know if this helps you.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, Sure thing from next time, how to accomplish this if my destination files are in date partitioned folders, i want the source record to be checked in all of the files recursively in all destination folders and if found in any of the destination files, it has to be removed, i don't want to write the destination anywhere else

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, Any luck?

Comment: @KiranKumar, I think I already provided solution.

Answer (score 2):

One cut and one grep should be enough

```
cut -d'|' -f1-17 source | grep -vFf- destination > new_destination
```

Comment: Be sure to add `-F` to `grep` in this case, otherwise the input line is interpreted as an ERE pattern, not a fixed string! (imagine a line contains `.*`)

Comment: @pacholik, nothing happened with this, my source and destination files remained same

Answer (score 0):

Following awk should be able to help you in same.

```
awk -F"|" 'FNR==NR{a[$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17];next} !(($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17) in a)' Source_file  Destination_file  > temp_file && mv temp_file  Destination_file
```

Adding a non-one line form for solution too now.

```
awk -F"|" '
FNR==NR{
  a[$1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17];
  next
}
!(($1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$14,$15,$16,$17) in a)
'   Source_file  Destination_file  > temp_file && mv temp_file  Destination_file
```